# Finding detailed relief map of Russia?

Tags: data, russia

I need to find a relief map of Russia. Where such a map can be found and downloaded?

Or how to create such a map?

I have found a [site](https://maps-for-free.com/), but the scale is too small.

Comment: What is the purpose of using such a map? Do you need a large-scale map?

Comment: @Taras I am animating models on the arcgis scene. Need offline mode with well-traced terrain. Yes,  need a large-scale map.

Comment: What if you check this source [OpenTopoMap](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=OpenTopoMap)

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.